# Trouble on using the i18n gem with view files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, view, internationalization

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1 and I would like to know how to correctly handle internationalization related to view files. That is, ...

... in my `app/views/users/flag.html.erb` file I have:

```
<% content_for :page_title do %> 
  <%= t(:test_key) %>
<% end %>
```

... in my `config/locales/views/users/en.yml` file (*note*: I am organizing files as stated in the [official RoR guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#organization-of-locale-files)) I have:

```
en:
  views:
    users:
      flag:
        test_key: Test text
```

When I browse the `flag` page the `t(:test_key)` is not translated. **What is wrong in the `config/locales/views/users/en.yml` file? How can I make it to work?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to read a bit further down on that guide, until you reach the "Lazy lookup" part.

Try `t('.test_key')` instead of `t(:test_key)`. The difference is in the dot.

Comment: I opened a question in order to know the "subtle" difference between using t(:test_key) and t('.test_key'): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767219/i18n-what-is-the-difference-between-using-ttest-key-and-t-test-key